# given the distance of each of the four diagonal planes of a tetrahedron from the origin, is there a formula for finding each of the four vertices?

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

I have a definition of a regular tetrahedron by the distance of each plane from the origin. 
If the distance is negative, the plane is on the far (negative Z) side of the origin. 
The four planes are named after the four cartesian quadrants: i, ii, iii, and iv, in a right-hand rule coordinate system, 
such that positive i places the plane up (positive Y), to the right (positive X), and closer (positive Z). 
All positive values define planes with positive Z-axis intercepts.

[image: regular tetrahedron]
In the image, the green face is `i`, `ii` is red, `iii` is blue, and `iv` is opposite (not shown).

So for a tetrahedron with i=sqrt(3), ii=0, iii=0, and iv=0 
the vertices (in no particular order) would be (0,0,0), (1,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1).

I feel like I should be able to solve this. I'm not sure what's blocking me.

Comment: I haven't thought this idea through, but your inputs are barycentric coordinates. The sum of those distances must be the altitude of the tetrahedron. After you find the tetrahedron the inputs will be the barycentric coordinates of the origin. It will be interior if the inputs are all positive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's equivalent to finding the insphere of the tetrahedron, which there is a formula for.